# C++ Replacing arrays with structs and using a loop

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I currently have the following working code which calculates interest depending on some conditions.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int MAXACCOUNTS = 8;
int interest(double Balance[], int AccountNumber[], int DaysSinceDebited[],     int MAXACCOUNTS);

int main()
{
int AccountNumber[MAXACCOUNTS] = { 1001, 7940, 4382, 2651, 3020, 7168, 6245,   9342 };
 double Balance[MAXACCOUNTS] = { 4254.40, 27006.25, 123.50, 85326.92, 657.0,    7423.34, 4.99, 107864.44 };
 int DaysSinceDebited[MAXACCOUNTS] = { 20, 35, 2, 14, 5, 360, 1, 45 };
 int total = interest(Balance, AccountNumber, DaysSinceDebited, MAXACCOUNTS);
 cout << "total is:" << total << endl;
 system("pause");
}

int interest(double Balance[], int AccountNumber[], int DaysSinceDebited[], int MAXACCOUNTS) {

int total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < MAXACCOUNTS; i++)
{

    if (Balance[i] > 10000 || DaysSinceDebited[i] > 30)
    {
        total = Balance[i] / 100 * 1.06;
        cout << "Account Number " << AccountNumber[i] << "," << "Balance " << Balance[i] << "," << "Interest: " << total << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        total = Balance[i] / 100 * 1.03;
        cout << "Account Number " << AccountNumber[i] << "," << "Balance " << Balance[i] << "," << "Interest: " << total << endl;
    }

}
return total;



system("pause");
}
```

I have attempted to do the second part of this task:

Change your program so that it no longer uses separate arrays, but instead declares a struct called Account for the information for each of the bank accounts, and declares instead an array of Accounts, initialised with the same information.

Modify your loop so that it uses the array of structs rather than the separate arrays. You should produce the same display, because the information is the same. It should also work out which account generated the highest amount of interest and display the relevant account number.

Here is my attempt:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int MAXACCOUNTS = 8;
int interest(Account accounts[], int MAXACCOUNTS);



struct Account
{
    int Number;
    double Balance;
    int DaysSinceDebited;
};

int main()
{
    int Accountnumber;
    double Balance;
    int DaysSinceDebited;
    Account accounts[MAXACCOUNTS];

    accounts[0].Number = 1001;
    accounts[0].Balance = 4254.40;
    accounts[0].DaysSinceDebited = 20;

    accounts[1].Number = 7940;
    accounts[1].Balance = 270006.25;
    accounts[1].DaysSinceDebited = 35;

    accounts[2].Number = 4382;
    accounts[2].Balance = 123.50;
    accounts[2].DaysSinceDebited = 2;

    accounts[3].Number = 2651;
    accounts[3].Balance = 85326.92;
    accounts[3].DaysSinceDebited = 14;

    accounts[4].Number = 3020;
    accounts[4].Balance = 657.0;
    accounts[4].DaysSinceDebited = 5;

    accounts[5].Number = 7168;
    accounts[5].Balance = 7423.34;
    accounts[5].DaysSinceDebited = 360;

    accounts[6].Number = 6285;
    accounts[6].Balance = 4.99;
    accounts[6].DaysSinceDebited = 1;

    accounts[7].Number = 9342;
    accounts[7].Balance = 107964.44;
    accounts[7].DaysSinceDebited = 45;

    system("pause");
}

int interest(Account accounts[], int MAXACCOUNTS) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < accounts[i]; i++)
    {
        if (accounts[i].Balance > 10000 || accounts[i].DaysSinceDebited > 30)
        {
            total = accounts[i].Balance / 100 * 1.06;

            cout << "Account Number: " << accounts[i].Number << "Balance " <<   accounts[i].Balance << "DaysSinceDebited " << accounts[i].DaysSinceDebited <<   endl;
       }
       else
       {
            total = accounts[i].Balance / 100 * 1.03;
            cout << "Account Number: " << accounts[i].Number << "Balance " << accounts[i].Balance << "DaysSinceDebited " << accounts[i].DaysSinceDebited << endl;
       }
    }
    return total;

    system("pause");
}
```

This is my first time using structs so there are some errors and syntax errors, i would really appreciate if someone could perhaps fix the code so i can study the syntax and how its done

Comment: So what are those errors? **Edit** your post and include that important piece of information.

Comment: You should change your function so it accepts your structure instead of three numbers. You should create array of accounts instead of 8 variables. interest(Account) doesn't make sense, you can't pass structure name as a parameter and also as for now you function requires 4 parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of accountone, accounttwo, ... you must make an array of Accout in main.

```
Account accounts[MAXACCOUNTS];
```

Then you need to initialize the individual members:

```
accounts[0].Number = 1001;
accounts[0].Balance = 4254.40;
accounts[0].DaysSinceDebited = 20;

accounts[1].Number = 7940;
accounts[1].Balance =  270006.25;
accounts[1].DaysSinceDebited = 35;
```

and so on....

You could also make a member function in the struct like:

```
initialize(int number, double balance, int daysSinceDebited)
{
     Number = number;
     Balance = balance;
     DaysSinceDebited = daysSinceDebited;
}
```

and use it like:

```
accounts[0].initialize(1001, 4154.40, 20);
accounts[1].initialize(7940, 270006.25, 35);
```

and so on.

Or you could try:

```
Account accounts[MAXACCOUNTS] = {
    {1001, 4154.40, 20},
    {7940, 270006.25, 35},
    ..... next initializers until you reach MAXACCOUNTS
    .....
};
```

Also you must change the interest function to take an array of Account.
Something like:

```
int interest(Account accounts[], int MAXACCOUNTS);
```

Comment: i have changed my code around and almost fixed it, the only problems left is to do with this part of the code, int interest(Account accounts[], int MAXACCOUNTS) {

 int total = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < accounts[i]; i++                          Could you provide some help?

Comment: Don't do `for (int i = 0; i < accounts[i]; i++)` It shall be `for (int i = 0; i < MAXACCOUNTS; i++)`

Comment: thankyou. lastly, just got two errors with this line, i understand the rest of the code. Tried to prototype the function: int interest(Account accounts[], int MAXACCOUNTS);            errors were 'Account' undeclared identifier and missing a ) before 'accounts'

Comment: It is because Account isn't know at the place you have the prototype. Move the line `int interest(Account accounts[], int MAXACCOUNTS);` so that it is AFTER the struct and just BEFORE main. BTW - you can remove `    int Accountnumber; double Balance; int DaysSinceDebited;` from main now. They are not used.